# Is a general solution of an ODE always unique?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y^{(n)} = F(t,y,\dots,y^{(n-1)})$ be an ODE of order $n$.

In all treatments of ODEs that I have seen, it is assumed that if $u(t,c_1, \dots, c_n)$ is a general solution of this ODE then it is unique, i.e. $\nexists v: I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $v^{(n)} = F(t,v,\dots,v^{(n-1)}) \ \& \ \nexists c_1, \dots, c_n \in \mathbb{R} : v(t) = u(t,c_1, \dots, c_n)$ .

Then they go on to show that **if** $u$ is a linear combination of linearly independent particular solutions (their Wronskian is nonzero) then it satisfies the ODE and a well-defined IVP. See for example [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/FundamentalSetsofSolutions.aspx) and [here](https://www.math.psu.edu/srikrish/math251/notes/fundamentalsols.pdf).

Shouldn't we prove that all solutions are of this form? And how do we prove this?

**P.S.** I've found that Picard–Lindelöf theorem proves this for a first-order IVP with some additional hypotheses. I am more interested about just the ODE with no initial conditions.

Comment: Note that the fact that a linear combination of solutions is a solution is valid only for linear equations.

Comment: Note that the term "particular solution" is most often reserved for the solution of the inhomogeneous linear equation. There you need convex combinations, i.e., the coefficients sum to $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same is true for higher order ODE. The assumptions of Picard-Lindelöf or Cauchy carry back from the formulation as a first order system. Continuity of $F$ in $t$ is always assumed.

If $F$ is Lipschitz in the vector $(y,y',...,y^{n-1})$ then so is the first-order system and a solution exists globally and is unique.

If $F$ is continuously differentiable in $(y,y',...,y^{n-1})$, then so is the first-order system and a unique solution exists locally around the initial point and is unique (also its continuation to the border of the domain is unique).

---

**Update:** As to your links and refined problem: Linear ODE with continuous coefficients are always Lipschitz, this is a consequence of linearity. The bijectivity between initial conditions and constants in linear combination of a fundamental system is directly equivalent to the Wronskian determinant not being zero.

Comment: So uniqueness for IVP implies uniqueness for the ODE only?

Comment: What is uniqueness for the ODE without any initial point? The IVP is uniquely solvable at least locally wherever the assumptions are satisfied.

Comment: I think I clarified it in my question. For example we solve $y''(t) + y(t) = 0$ and guess a family of solutions $u = c_1 \cos(t) + c_2 \sin(t)$. Are all solutions described by this? Why?

Comment: Of course, $F(t,y,y')=-y$ is Lipschitz in $(y,y')$. Every IVP has a unique solution extending over the whole of the integration interval. The relation between $(y(t_0),y'(t_0))$ and $(c_1,c_2)$ is bijective for any $t_0$.

Comment: Ok, so why is it bijective? Maybe you can give a reference?

Comment: That is the whole point of the definition of the Wronski matrix and determinant. Reread your notes. In this special case the transformation matrix, the Wronskian, is a rotation matrix.